# No Suitable method found to override OnInteract c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to build my game in Unity and during the process of making the chest and signpost interactable, I suddenly got an error. The error keeps saying " No Suitable method found to override"

I've tried looking at my own code and changing the names. I think it has to do with me naming it "Character character". While I do have a public void for this. I keep getting the same error.

This is the code I have for opening and changing the sprites of the chest.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InteractableChest : InteractableBase
{
    public Sprite OpenChestSprite;
    public ItemType ItemInChest;
    public int Amount;

    private bool m_IsOpen;
    private SpriteRenderer m_Renderer;

    void Awake()
    {
        m_Renderer = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    public override void OnInteract( Character character )
    {
        if( m_IsOpen == true )
        {
            return;
        }

        character.Inventory.AddItem( ItemInChest, Amount, PickupType.FromChest );
        m_Renderer.sprite = OpenChestSprite;
        m_IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be at

```
public override void OnInteract( Character character )
    {
        if( m_IsOpen == true )
        {
            return;
        }
```

Since all the files with "Character character" are affected by this.
In my Characterinteractionmodel document I made a snippet of the following code:

```
[RequireComponent( typeof ( Character ) ) ]
public class CharacterInteractionModel : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Character m_Character;
    private Collider2D m_Collider;
    private CharacterMovementModel m_MovementModel;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        m_Character = GetComponent<Character>();
        m_Collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        m_MovementModel = GetComponent<CharacterMovementModel>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }


    public void OnInteract()
    {
        InteractableBase usableInteractable = FindUsableInteractable();

        if( usableInteractable == null )
        {
          return;
        }

        usableInteractable.OnInteract( m_Character );

    }
```

In all the corrupted files (The ones with the character in it) I have the same erorr which states "Error CS0115: 'InteractableChest.OnInteract(Character)': No Suitable Method Found to Override

Interactbase document:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InteractableBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    virtual public void OnInteract()
    {
        Debug.LogWarning( "OnInteract is not implemented" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to override a method, you need to match its signature and your base class doesn't have a parameter list:

```
virtual public void OnInteract()
```

Your derived class requires a `Character` parameter:

```
public override void OnInteract( Character character )
```

So in order to fix it, you need that parameter in you base class's method, even if it doesn't use it:

```
virtual public void OnInteract( Character character )
```